# Sqoop import from IBM db2 to Hive

Tags: hadoop, db2, sqoop

I was trying to import data from db2 to hdfs, got below error with respect to this specific database. I am new to DB2, this error seems to be more related to db2 database and driver.

> sqoop import --connect jdbc:db2://db2_host101:60006/DB_NAME --username
>   hduser  --table repo.table_abc --hive-import --hive-overwrite
>   --hive-table repo.table_abc --target-dir /target_dir/table_abc -m 1 -P

Error:

```
An attempt was made to access a database, DB_NAME, which was either not found or does not support transactions. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08004
```

Do transactions needs to be enabled on DB2 for sqoop to work. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by reaching out to our db2 DBA. I was using the wrong "DB_NAME", so the first part in the error statement was correct, It was unable to find the database. Though, second part of the error confused me initially.